# SQL count function not working

Tags: sql, count

I want to count the number of instances where tuition does not equal 99999.99, but I am having a hard time getting the SQL count function to work. I have the following query:

```
select  
    year, college,
    case
        when tuition < 99999.99 then 'Other'
        else to_char(tuition)
    end tuition, 
    count(*) as tuition_count
from
    enrolment
group by    
    year, college, tuition
order by    
    year, college, tuition
```

I was expecting the following results, with the count for "Other" rolled up.

```
YEAR    COLLEGE     TUITION     TUITION_COUNT
---------------------------------------------
2012    CollegeA    Other       123
2012    CollegeA    99999.99    456
```

Instead, I am getting multiple instances of "Other", one for each distinct value of tuition.

```
YEAR    COLLEGE     TUITION     TUITION_COUNT
---------------------------------------------
2012    CollegeA    Other       100
2012    CollegeA    Other       20
2012    CollegeA    Other       3
2012    CollegeA    99999.99    456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by (in the group by statement) what you want.  Like this:

```
select  year, college,  case
                          when tuition < 99999.99 then 'Other'
                          else to_char(tuition)
                        end as tuition, count(*) as tuition_count
from enrolment
group by year, college, case
                          when tuition < 99999.99 then 'Other'
                          else to_char(tuition)
                        end
order by year, college, case
                          when tuition < 99999.99 then 'Other'
                          else to_char(tuition)
                        end
```

This looks nicer:

```
select  year, college, tuition, count(*) as tuition_count
from 
(
  select  year, college,  case
                            when tuition < 99999.99 then 'Other'
                            else to_char(tuition)
                          end as tuition
  from enrolment
) subselect
group by year, college, tuition
order by year, college, tuition
```